# Overlay text on a picture with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I just wanted to write some text on picture (possibly with some simple effects like shadow). How can I do this with PIL?

Comment: Are there non-PIL alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First install Python Imaging Library (`pip install Pillow`)

Note: you may need to change the path to your font file `font_fname`.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont

font_fname = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf'
font_size = 200
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_fname, font_size)

h, w = 1080, 1920
bg_colour = (255, 255, 255)
bg_image = np.dot(np.ones((h,w,3), dtype='uint8'), np.diag(np.asarray((bg_colour), dtype='uint8')))
image0 = Image.fromarray(bg_image)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image0)
draw.text((530, 160), "hello world", font=font, fill='rgb(0, 0, 0)')
image0.save('hello_world.jpg')
```

Comment: How to add the special effects (like shadows, dilation, noise, etc)?