# Add text to an image in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, text

[app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGsCT.png) I have an app with GUI in which user can browse his filesystem and choose a picture (of a certificate) to apply his name on the picture at the specific coordinates (name is predefined atm).
And I'm having a problem with adding a text to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay text on a picture with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110342/overlay-text-on-a-picture-with-pil)

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115925/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import ImageFont,ImageDraw,Image
image= Image.open("certificate.png") #Opened certificate image
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(image)  #created object for image
font=ImageFont.truetype("Fontsah.ttf",40)   #Defined font you can download any font and use it.
username="Ultimus"
xcor=200    #x-coordinate and y-coordinate to write in certi
ycor=300
draw.text((xcor,ycor),username,font=font,fill=(0,0,0,255))  #here we draw
image.save("ImageName1.png")    #here we save new image
```

Here's the code just set `xcor` and `ycor` according to certificate also download good font for your certificate and just replace `Fontsah.ttf` to your font name e.g. `arial.ttf`.

You can download `Fontsah.ttf` [from this repository](https://github.com/ultimus11/Text-to-Handwriting-ultimate-)

Also you can check out more complex application of this code [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xsmm75saHI).

Last but not the least install Pillow library `pip install Pillow`